# Using fetch() in Laravel with VueJS 3

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I just started to learn Vue 3 with Laravel, and I created an app where I have this:

Post Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'content'
    ];
}
```

In `PostsController`, I have this function where I want to get all posts:

```
 public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::all();
        return response()->json([
            'posts' => $posts,
        ], 200);
    }
```

In `routes/api.php`:

```
Route::get('/posts', [PostsController::class, 'index']);
```

And this is my Vue Component:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="post in posts" :key="post">
                {{post.title}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            posts: []
        }
    },
    created(){
      fetch('http://vue-laravel.test/api/posts')
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
        })
       
    },
    methods:{
       
    }
}
</script>
```

This is the sample data:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "List of all Posts",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Second",
            "content": "Second post",
            "created_at": "2021-01-27T08:08:21.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-01-27T08:08:21.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "First",
            "content": "This is my first post",
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null
        }
    ]
}
```

BUT when I `console.log` this fetch, I get this:

[image: screenshot]

With `console.log(response.data)`, I get `undefined`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resolved result of `fetch()` (a `Body` object) should be converted to JSON with [`Body.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json):

```js
fetch('http://vue-laravel.test/api/posts')
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(json => this.posts = json.data)
```

Comment: Yes i get it with json.posts.. 5 minutes before that i tried with :
async getPosts(){
          const response = await fetch('http://vue-laravel.test/api/posts')
          const responseData = await response.json()
        console.log(responseData.posts)
          this.posts = responseData.posts
           
       },

And again i have success